# How to connect to local VNC server? Connecting from external network just works

Tags: raspberry-pi, vnc, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 set up on my home network with the VNC server running. I have set up port forwarding from my home router to the Raspberry Pi and I can connect using VNC when using the external IP address.

However, when I'm on my home network I *cannot* connect to the Pi using the local IP address `192.168.0.4`. It's seems odd that I can connect as if I'm external to my home network, but I can't connect when I come from the internal network.

Comment: Perhaps your wired LAN is separated from your wireless LAN

Comment: So my Pi is connected wirelessly. When I try to connect from another wireless computer, it fails. When I try to connect with a wired computer, there is no problem.

Comment: Perhaps wireless client isolation hard at work

Comment: @ti7 I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that nor how I would check/disable.

Comment: Ah - it would be a setting in your router's wireless LAN settings called that (it's a common and general security feature to prevent wireless clients from interacting, as the majority of users just consume and so this protects against some virus transmission)

Comment: Thanks @ti7 I’ll go looking for some settings.